# What is the failure rate of dental students in Japanese universities?

Tags: graduation, japan

If you pass a dental degree from a Japanese university, you automatically get a licence to practice. Therefore we have have a lot of dentists in Japan. The pertinent basic question of quality of dentists is how many fail university. What are some statistics on that?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! Could you please edit your question and give imformation about where you already searched for this information?

Comment: "The pertinent basic question of quality of dentists is how many fail university" - this makes very little sense as a measure of quality. The quality of dentists is based on the care they provide.

Comment: It makes sense if none of them fail then any entry-level dentist that you see will be potentially very poor. In any field where it is hard to assess the ability of a worker then you have look at the quality of the education as a test.

Comment: How is this a shopping question? It looks for a piece of statistics on a nation-wide level.

Comment: @sgf The reason listed for closing is not always the actual reason, due in large part to the limited number of choices.  That said, I don't entirely see the reason for closing either.

Comment: @sgf Sometimes I feel questions are closed because nobody knows an answer from the top of their head.

Comment: @user2617804 The problem is that the quality of education isn't directly related to the fail rate. If I mumble incoherently in a lecture and produce a final that's unrelated to what I've mumbled about, the fail rate might well be 100% but I've hardly provided perfect instruction. On the other hand, a dental program teaching every student everything they need to know (bit of a pipe dream, I know), and thus providing an excellent education, might approach 100% pass rate. The statistics may still be interesting, but would need more analysis if you want to say anything about the education quality.

Comment: @user2617804 Or it means that only students with a high likelihood to succeed are admitted. Failure rates by themselves tell you very little about those who succeed. For example, Harvard has a 98% graduation rate. UMass-Lowell has a 56% graduation rate. It would be easy to gather a high fail rate by admitting students who cannot succeed, but this isn't necessarily a mark of a bad approach, either: it could be that you prefer to admit students with minimal requirements and let the coursework weed people out.

Comment: If very few of them fail, couldn't that also mean that the system is just very good at training them, or at pre-selecting the talented ones at the admission stage?